# OSX get process resource usage

Tags: macos

I am search for an API in OSX to get the process list of my current session and memory consumption/CPU usage of each process on the system.

Is there such API ?

Comment: related with sample code in Python: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems